# creating a graph using python matplotlib from range(1,100000)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, integer-overflow

creating array using numpy from 1 to 100000 as value of x and y = x*x

```
x = np.arange(1,100000)
y = x*x
```

but when checked y value there are 31k+ negative value

```
count = 0
for i in y:
    if i < 0:
        count+=1
print(count)
```

31612

> [image: working on jupyter notebook]

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/sandeep-agrawal-3b8857196_python-python3-pythonlearning-activity-6852679546345521152-cG-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably having integer overflow, try convert `x` to float before raising the power:

```
x = np.arange(1,100000)
y = x**10

sum(y < 0)
49760
```

Convert to float:

```
x = np.arange(1,100000).astype(float)
y = x**10

sum(y < 0)
0
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'm using an older numpy. It's likely some autocast has been added to the latest version. @Murali

Comment: I cannot reproduce this results on my machine. It is 0 in both cases

Comment: @Murali You are probably running a 64-bit numpy version, while Psidom runs a 32-bit version.

Comment: @Murali Indeed this example can't reproduce in 1.21.2. Probably. due to the use of a larger int type. If you try `y = x ** 10`, you will still have this problem.

Comment: @JohanC yes, I am using a 64 bit Numpy version

Comment: @JohanC Makes sense, I'm testing this in the browser, and it's runing 32 bit version of numpy :)

Comment: @Murali As float or as integer ? Neither gives me 0 if I test it in a 64 bit version.

Comment: Sorry. It was float.